# Find matches couples to maximize a sum

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create 6 couples, one agent is assign to one product. So that each agent is assign to one product and one product has only one agent assigned.

I want to maximize the sum generated by the couples created and print on different cell the couples created

[image: datas]

and then write the result on these cells

[image]

Is there a way to do that ? Using VBA or not ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like pictures.... ()

[image: picture of attached excel with formulas]

When entering all combination of 1-6 in E46:J46, and below

And copying the formulas from K46:Q46

You will, eventually finding the max value in column Q

But, i agree, a solution in VBA would be so much cleaner...

Switching between 'Show formulas' and 'Dont show formulas' can be done using CTRL+`

[image: second picture, showing values]

Comment: Thanks a lot, i thought about this solution without knowing how to do it ! I will try to apply it if it's not too long (it's 6! possibilities)